# Gaussian distribution and dot product

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

If $u_1, \dots, u_n$ is an orthonormal basis for ${\bf R}^n$, and ${X}$ a random variable taking values in ${{\bf R}^n}$ with the standard Gaussian distribution, in the sense that

$\displaystyle \mathop{\bf P}( X \in S ) = \int_S \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} e^{-\|x\|^2/2}\ dx$ for measurable $S \subset {\bf R}^n$,

why is $X \cdot u_i$ a real random variable with the pdf of the univariate standard Gaussian distribution. i.e, why is $\displaystyle \mathop{\bf P}( X \cdot u_i \in S ) = \int_S \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}\ dx$ for measurable $S \subset {\bf R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be the $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix with columns $u_1, \ldots, u_n$. Let $Y = U^\top X$. Then using rotational invariance of the standard Gaussian distribution, we have
\begin{align}
P(Y \in S) &= P(U^\top X \in S)
\\
&= \int_{\{x : U^\top x \in S\}} (2\pi)^{-n/2} e^{-\|x\|^2/2} \, dx
\\
&= \int_S (2\pi)^{-n/2} e^{-\|Uy\|^2/2} \, dy
& y=U^\top x
\\
&= \int_S (2\pi)^{-n/2} e^{-\|y\|^2/2} \, dy
& \|Uy\|^2 = \|y\|^2
\\
&= P(X \in S)
\end{align}
for $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

So $Y=U^\top X$ has the same distribution as $X$. In particular,
$Y_i = X \cdot u_i$ has the same distribution as $X_i$. So,
\begin{align}
P(X \cdot u_i \in I)
&= P(X_i \in I)
\\
&= \int_{x_i \in I} (2\pi)^{-n/2} e^{-\|x\|^2/2} \, dx
\\
&= \left(\int_I (2\pi)^{-1/2} e^{-x_i^2/2} \, dx_i\right) \left(\prod_{j \ne i} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (2\pi)^{-1/2} e^{-x_j^2/2} \, dx_j\right)
\\
&= \int_I (2\pi)^{-1/2} e^{-x_i^2/2} \, dx_i
\end{align}
for $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sure, how did I miss the obvious fact that $\displaystyle {\bf P}(X \cdot v_i \in S_i) = {\bf P}(UX \in {\bf R} \times \dots \times S_i/|v_i| \times \dots \times {\bf R})$. Rotational invariance is indeed sufficient.